# Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones :RIGIFY connecting mesh with bones

Tags: modifiers, bones, rigify

hello i want to connect my face mesh with rigify bones

when i tried to parent mesh with bones

im getting this error :

```
Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones
```

I'm new to blender i've researched a bit about it

searched about the same in all other threads

but nothing seems to be worked

and followed this tutorial

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuHkd61RhDs
```

but still its of no use

im not sure how to connect rigify bones to my mesh properly and use it

attached my blender file please have a look

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bc7vx7svbvywv7/eyes%20faceschnaged.blend?dl=0
```

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: added the link in the question itself .
added dropbox link 
please check

Comment: apply the scale of both the head and the armature, move a bit the armature within the bead, parent, it seems to work

Comment: added scale to face mesh added scale and location to bones and tried to parent it 
still the same

Comment: done done its working thank you so much :D

Comment: Oh ok, nice, I didn't understand what you meant by "added scale to face mesh"   ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scale of both the head and the armature, move a bit the armature within the bead, parent, it seems to work